# Script for button "View Desktop Version"?

Tags: redirect, mobile, desktop

I want to make a link in footer of my mobile site version, pointing to desktop version of the site. But I have this script in desktop version:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width < 800) {
    window.location = "mysite.com/m/page1.html";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

If a make this link in mobile version:

```
<a href="mysite.com/page1.html">View desktop version</a>
```

the hypelink pointed to desktop site but desktop is redirecting back to mobile version and this is unended cycle of redirection.

How to make this:
- i have script in desktop version for redirect to mobile site
and
- if the mobile user want to view desktop version, clicking at the link "view desktop version" to go at desktop version without redirect back in mobile version?

Thanks

Comment: You could place a cookie on the user's machine which tells your page not to redirect to the mobile version. Or you could add a query parameter like `?redirecttomobile=false` and handle it that way. If you have any kind of session associated with the user, you could handle this in there, too.

Comment: hm, and how? How is the code?